# How can I get the input addresses of a transaction in Java?

Tags: transactions, address, bitcoinj, transaction-input

I am trying to obtain the addresses of entry of a transaction when I receive money, but I have not found the way. I have tried to create an address with the bytes obtained by calling `TransactionInput.getScriptSig().getPubKey()`, but I've only obtained a ScriptException. If I call `TransactionInput.getFromAddress()` (deprecated) the code is frozen. I don't want to have to make a call to the API of block explorer, it is too cumbersome. Is there any way of doing this? As it parses the transaction [blockhain.info](https://www.blochain.info) to get that kind of information?

Answer (score 1):

You should get the list of inputs, this is a snippet code using BitcoinJ to get input and outputs addresses:

```
List<TransactionInput> inputs = tx.getInputs();
List<TransactionOutput> outputs = tx.getOutputs();

for (TransactionOutput out : outputs) {
   System.out.println("addresses in output " + out.getAddressFromP2PKHScript(params));
}
for (TransactionInput in : inputs) {
    System.out.println("addresses in input " + in.getFromAddress());
}
```